# Plotly - how all the data point in x and y axis and adjust the size of chart depends on number of data points

Tags: python, plot, charts, plotly, streamlit

I wrote the code as follows to plot the scatter plot using Plotly and I just want to use this library.

- how can I get rid of this messy x and y axis when I want to show all data?
- how can I adjust the size of chart depends on number of data points that is showing ? because the chart is connected to some streamlit filter and is dynamic, depends what I choose.
- I also when I use all the data point, the x axis is messy, is there anyway to adjust the plot ?

```
def chart(df):

    
    color_discrete_map = {'df1': 'rgb(255,0,0)',
                      'df2': 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                      'df3': '#11FCE4',
                      'df4': '#9999FF',
                      'df5': '#606060',
                      'df6': '#CC6600'}


    fig = px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='SOURCE', width=1200,
                     height=800,color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

    fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')

    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=250, r=0, t=0, b=20),

    )
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%y-%m", tickmode = 'linear',  tick0 = 0.5,dtick = 0.75))

    fig.update_xaxes(ticks= "outside",
                     ticklabelmode= "period", 
                     tickcolor= "black", 
                     ticklen=10, 
                     minor=dict(
                         ticklen=4,  
                         dtick=7*24*60*60*1000,  
                         tick0="2016-07-03", 
                         griddash='dot', 
                         gridcolor='white')
                    )
    
    fig.update_layout(yaxis={"dtick":1},margin={"t":0,"b":0},height=500)
```

[image]

Update :

I was able to add the code as follows to make the slider for x axis, so now the question is how can I make slider for y axis ?

```
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list([
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="1m",
                         step="month",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=6,
                         label="6m",
                         step="month",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="YTD",
                         step="year",
                         stepmode="todate"),
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="1y",
                         step="year",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(step="all")
                ])
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(
                visible=True
            ),
            type="date"
        )
    )
    fig.update_xaxes(tickformat = '%Y-%B', dtick='M1')
```